# Asp.net webform site displays "Localhost Refused to connect" when Redirecting to next Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, webforms, localhost

I have been running an ERP on my localhost, and it was working fine until I encountered a Just-in-time debugger dialog in Visual Studio. When I cancelled the dialog, it caused my login session to time out. After restarting my system and trying to log in again, I now receive a "LocalHost refused to connect" error when the next page tries to load after submitting my login details.

So far, I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Deleted the Visual Studio folder in the project folder
- Disabled my firewall
- Restarted IIS

Can anyone suggest other possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had to look critically at the Bindings config in my iis and noticed that the ports changed, what i had was 91 instead of 90 for some weird reasons. I also reset the physical path again, restarted visual studio and the website service and it worked.